Inclusion of Grassmannians Induces Isomorphism on Cohomology
Let $\text{Gr}_2^+(\mathbb{R}^n)$ denote the the Grassmannian of oriented $2$-planes in $\mathbb{R}^n$, i.e. the orientation-double-cover of the usual Grassmannian $\text{Gr}_2(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Let $i : \text{Gr}_2^+(\mathbb{R}^n) \hookrightarrow \text{Gr}_2^+(\mathbb{R}^\infty) \simeq \mathbb{CP}^\infty$ denote the canonical inclusion. I am trying to prove the following:

The inclusion $i$ induces isomorphisms $\mathbb{Z}[e] \cong H^*(\text{Gr}_2^+(\mathbb{R}^\infty)) \to H^*(\text{Gr}_2^+(\mathbb{R}^n))$ for all degrees $* < n-2$.

Using a homology-pair-LES argument together with Hurewicz (more specifically Hatcher, Theorem 4.32) it suffices to show that

$\text{Gr}_2^+(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is simply connected.
The pair $(\text{Gr}_2^+(\mathbb{R}^\infty), \text{Gr}_2^+(\mathbb{R}^n))$ is $(n-3)$-connected.

The first item is fine. For the second item I tried using Corollary 4.12 in Hatcher, i.e. I need to show that the pair is a CW-pair (an argument for this can be found in Hatcher's book on vector bundles) and that all cells in $\text{Gr}_2^+(\mathbb{R}^\infty) \setminus \text{Gr}_2^+(\mathbb{R}^n)$ have dimension $> n-3$. But this last step false in general I believe, since $\text{Gr}_2^+(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is not the $k$-skeleton of $\text{Gr}_2^+(\mathbb{R}^\infty)$ for any $k \in \mathbb{N}$, so in general this difference could still contain cells of dimension smaller than $n-3$. At least in the literature I have not found any statement about $\text{Gr}_2^+(\mathbb{R}^n)$ being some skeleton of $\text{Gr}_2^+(\mathbb{R}^\infty)$, even though it is possible to show some related properties; for instance that $\text{Gr}_2^+(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is a finite sub-complex of dimension exactly $2n-4$.
Question: Can I modify my arguments to give a coherent proof, or do I need a different proof altogether?
Remark 1: For reference, this problem can be found on p. 8 of Galatius' lecture notes on the Madsen-Weiss Theorem.
Remark 2: An alternative approach uses Hatcher Lemma 4D.2, namely if there exists an $(n-3)$-connected pair of spaces $(B,A)$ and a fibre bundle $p: \text{Gr}_2^+(\mathbb{R}^\infty) \to B$ with $p^{-1}(A) = \text{Gr}_2^+(\mathbb{R}^n)$, then the pair $(\text{Gr}_2^+(\mathbb{R}^\infty), \text{Gr}_2^+(\mathbb{R}^n))$ is also $(n-3)$-connected. However, so far I have not been able to come up with a pair satisfying these properties.
Remark 3: A third approach I can think of is to identify the quotient $\text{Gr}_2^+(\mathbb{R}^\infty) / \text{Gr}_2^+(\mathbb{R}^n)$ with some known space $X$ for which we have $H^k(X, *) \cong 0$ for all $k < n-2$, since we know that CW-pairs are good pairs. By a LES argument the original claim would follow. However I fail to come up with a suitable space $X$.
Any help or hints are appreciated!

I think you can obtain this as a byproduct of the calculation of the cohomology of Grassmannians, depending on what method you use to do so.

@Thorgott Thanks for the hint, I'll see if I can make it work!
